# How to decide if a statement needs to be placed in DispatchQueue.main.async?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am trying to get a subview's bound size in viewDidLoad: (the `canvas.bounds`)

Initially I did not use the `DispatchQueue.main.async` wrapper, and the size is not returned correctly. So by experiment, I wrapped the statement in main thread queue. Then it worked.

I know there is a guideline saying that "UI related operation needs to be placed in main thread". But how does this translates into actual coding rule of thumb:

1. If I am just querying a UI property, like getting bounds size, do I
   need to wrap it inside main thread queue?
2. If I am changing a UI
   property, e.g. change the bounds size, do I need to wrap it inside
   the main thread queue? (likely yes I guess)

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

   // stack views
   view.addSubview(photoView)
   view.addSubview(canvas)

   DispatchQueue.main.async {
       self.canvas.startPoint = CGPoint.zero
       self.canvas.endPoint = CGPoint(x: self.canvas.bounds.width / 2.0, y: self.canvas.bounds.height)

       self.canvas.setNeedsDisplay()
   }
   ```

Actually this leads to another question I want to ask naturally: having to wrap code in dispatch main looks “unclean”. If u have to wrap it , doesn’t it mean ‘viewDidLoad’ is not the correct life cycle to use? There should be a more appropriate life cycle that doesn’t require dispatch main wrapper?

Answer (score 5):

Your issue is that `viewDidLoad` is not the correct place to get the size of anything. It's too soon.

Using `DispatchQueue.main.async` simply delays that code just enough that the size has been updated (maybe).

The proper solution is to get the size in the proper place. Use either `viewDidAppear` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: Thanks. That confirms my guess then. Is it correct that: first option is to find an existing lifecycle to insert my logic; second option is to use dispatchmain if no such lifecycle exists, more like a hack.

Comment: There really is just one valid option - use the correct lifecycle method.